# How to login user based on email and password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a login page and struggling to find a solution. Here is what I have so far. I have tried to different things like use passwordAsync and EmailAsync but not working. I am using entity core framework.

Controller

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SignUpContext _signUp;
        private readonly LoginContext _login;
        public AccountController(SignUpContext signUp, LoginContext login)
        {
            _signUp = signUp;
            _login = login;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(Login login)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


            }

            return View(login);
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult SignUp()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async  Task<IActionResult> SignUp([Bind("UserID,FirstName,LastName,Address1,Address2,City,State,Zipcode,Phone,Email,Password")]SignUp users)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _signUp.Add(users);
                await _signUp.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
            return View(users);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is a red underline below FindEmailAsync asking me to create an internal method. Is that supposed to happen. I am trying to authenticate User. Do you have any other method?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I made some edits. Sorry about that

Comment: Do you devleop with asp.net core identity or just want to check username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly provide the code you are trying to do the authentication inside ModelState.IsValid

```
 [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Login(Login login)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


            }

            return View(login);
        }
```

However, you can use the method below to do the authentication:

```
 ApplicationUser signedUser = UserManager.FindByEmail(model.Email);
            var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(signedUser.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
            switch (result)
            {
                case SignInStatus.Success:
                    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
                case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                    return View("Lockout");
                case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                    return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
                case SignInStatus.Failure:
                default:
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return PartialView(model);
            }
```